# Is it a good option to use contains() method of ArrayList in nested for loops w.r.t performance?

Tags: java

```
List<Employee> empsFromDB = repo.findAll(); //size m

List<Long> empIdsFromReq = req.getEmployeeIds();// size n

for(Employee emp: empsFromDB){
   empIdsFromReq.contains(emp.getEmployeeId());
}
```

Is the above code optimum `w.r.t` performance?

My approach has been to create a map of employee `Ids` as `key` and Employee as value and then retrieve the employees from map using the list of Ids.

My understanding is by using the second approach worst case is `m+n` operations whereas in the first approach its `m x n`, which I feel is not optimum.

Please advice.

Comment: HashSet should perform better than List

Comment: You're correct. A HashMap lookup is O(1). A list lookup is O(N). But the performance problem of that loop is probably negligible compared to loading all the employees from the database. That's what you should avoid. Unless of course you have very few employees, but then the loop will be fast enough anyway.

Comment: I'm not aware of your exact needs, but generally fetching all entities and filtering them in memory is a bad idea. You better ask DBMS to filter entities by ids for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a `HashSet` instead of a `List` you can improve performance.

`contains()` for a `HashSet` is `O(1)` compared to `O(n)` for a `List`, therefore you should never use a `List` if you can do it with a `HashSet`.